# what code is make to treeview node expand

Tags: c#, treeview, driveinfo

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drv.IsReady)
        {
            TreeNode t2 = new TreeNode();
            t2.Text = drv.Name;
            t2.Nodes.Add("");
            treeView.Nodes.Add(t2);
        }
    }
}
```

parent node don't expand to child node
how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all expanded nodes in treeview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596723/how-can-i-get-all-expanded-nodes-in-treeview)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand all nodes you can use the [TreeView.ExpandAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.expandall(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drv.IsReady)
        {
            TreeNode t2 = new TreeNode();
            t2.Text = drv.Name;
            t2.Nodes.Add("make this not empty to show a result");
            treeView.Nodes.Add(t2);

            treeView.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
}
```